# LinkedIN iOS login presenting controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, authentication, linkedin-api

I am trying to present a new view controller after I login through linkedin's OAuth.However I am getting this error.

2013-05-27 20:24:23.530 SessionLoginSample[26016:c07] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
2013-05-27 20:24:23.531 SessionLoginSample[26016:c07] YES

Here is the code I am using, any tips on fixing this will be appreciated.

```
- (IBAction)button_TouchUp:(UIButton *)sender
 {
oAuthLoginView = [[OAuthLoginView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

// register to be told when the login is finished
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(loginViewDidFinish:)
                                             name:@"loginViewDidFinish"
                                           object:oAuthLoginView];

[self presentModalViewController:oAuthLoginView animated:YES];
  }


 -(void) loginViewDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
 {

ViewController *NVC = [self.storyboard    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NextViewViewController"];
[self presentViewController:NVC animated:YES completion:nil];
NSLog(@"YES");

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 1 year old, but...

When is the notification coming in?

Without seeing the code for OAuthLoginView, I suspect that you are firing off the notification before you have dismissed the modal controller.  The underlying controller can't present the new view controller while the modal view controllers is still being displayed.